# When is the reduction needed?

Tags: c, openmp

I've written this code which reads a Matrix and it basically sums the values of the matrix... But my question would be, since I've tried doing the pragma in different ways, I found that the `reduction (+:sum)` wouldn't be necessary, but, I just don't know why, I might have missed the actual sense of the reduction system in this case. This would be the alternative: `#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j) reduction (+:sum)`

And this would be the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main ()
{

    printf("===MATRIX SUM===\n");
    printf("N ROWS: ");
    int i1; scanf("%d",&i1);
    printf("M COLUMNS: ");
    int j1; scanf("%d",&j1);
    int matrixA[i1][j1];

    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < i1; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < j1; j++){
            scanf("%d",&matriuA[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nMATRIX A: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < i1; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < j1; j++){
            printf("%d ", matrixA[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    int sum = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j)
        for (i = 0; i < i1; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < j1; j++){
                sum += matrixA[i][j];
           }


    printf("\nTHE RESULT IS: %d", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

And, I would like to ask, if there would be like, a better solution for the pragma reduction since I read that's the most efficient way.

Comment: you should put both the reduction and the `sum+=..`, because you want a single OpenMP thread to execute `sum+=...` AND do a reduction on the sum variable of each OpenMP thead.

Comment: If I understand what you mean by efficiency you would want simd reduction within each thread as well as the outer loop reduction even if it requires separate named inner and outer reduction variables.

Answer (score 5):

The code you posted is **not correct without the reduction clause**.

```
sum += matrixA[i][j];
```

Will cause a classic race condition when executed by multiple threads in parallel. Sum is a shared variable, but `sum += ...` is not an atomic operation.

```
(sum is initially 0, all matrix elements 1)
Thread 1                     |  Thread 2
-----------------------------------------------------------
tmp = sum + matrix[0][0] = 1 |
                             | tmp = sum + matrix[1][0] = 1
sum = tmp = 1                |
                             | sum = tmp = 1 (instead of 2)
```

The reduction fixes exactly this. With reduction, the loop will work on an implicit thread-local copy of the `sum` variable. At the end of the region, the original `sum` variable will be set to the sum of all thread-local copies (in a correct way without race-conditions).

Another solution would be to mark the `sum += ...` as atomic operation or critical section. That, however has a significant performance penalty.