# How to properly parallelize conditional loop using OpenMP?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to parallelize the following snippet to count the number of primes < than n.

```
static int primes_count(int n)
{
    int p = 0;
    int i;
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i) shared(n, p) default(none)
    for (i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (is_prime(i)) p++;
    }

    return p;
}
```

The problem is that I get different values every-time. However, if I remove the pragma line, the sequential approach yields deterministic values all the time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add `reduction(p)` and learn about reduction. There are gazillions of Q&A about that here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is the reduction needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819136/when-is-the-reduction-needed)

Comment: I would also add the ``schedule(guided)`` clause to reduce possible load imbalance due to the increasing execution time of ``is_prime(i)``.