# Spin off one statement in a loop parallel OpenMP

Tags: visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, openmp

I have a large C++ project(Windows VC++ 13) in which I have a costly loop. The loop is costly because one statement(which is another function call) is very expensive. I want to make that one line parallel. What I mean is, I dont want each to wait to completion. On coming to that line, I want to spin it off as a separate thread. End of the iteration I want all the threads to join and then I want to continue my execution. Is that possible? A simplified version of the problem I am solving is,

```
for(int i =0 ; i<limit; i++)
{
    //some processing and getting some value into a variable say x
    <value to use> += <costly function which taken in x as parameter>
   //some more processing
}
```

What I would like to do is, when it hits the line that calls the costly function, I would like it to spin off a thread. And in the end of the loop I would wait to join all the threads and continue execution. I obviously must not do a `parallel for` in openMP for the loop since that screws up the calculation of x and sends the same x to multiple calls of the function. Also I would prefer using OpenMP. Can somebody help with this please?

Comment: You can certainly do that with `async` and `future`, but you will need to collect your `future` results in a list or pre-reserved vector. How much hand-holding do you need?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are trying to achieve. Do you just want to overlap your `costly function` and `some more processing`, i.e., to run them concurrently, within each loop? Running two threads, i.e., utilizing just two cores, is enough for you?

Comment: @DanielLangr No, whaat I would like is the line that calls the `costly function` to run seperately for each loop without waiting for the previous iteration to complete

Comment: @user7795930 Then, why do you write that you want to _"join all the threads at the end of the iteration"_? You likely want to join them after the whole loop, is that right?

Comment: @user7795930 Also, I don't understand why do you want to start a new thread `limit` times? It would be inefficient, if `limit` is higher than hardware concurrency. Wouldn't be better to create as many threads as the hardware concurrency is (such as number of cores) and then spawn a new OpenMP `task` for each invocation of your function?

Comment: @DanielLangr I want to wait for the completion of all the threads in the end to proceed, thats what I meant by "join all the threads". Of course, I would be limiting the number of threads created, not number 'limit' number of threads. I would want to set the max number of threads I would spawn. Also, my important criterion is that each iteration should only create different thread, NEVER  two threads for the same iteration..

Comment: @user7795930 Sorry, but I don't understand. You write that _"I would want to set the max number of threads I would spawn."_ which should not be equal to `limit`. Then, you write that _"each iteration should only create different thread"_. Both statements are in contradiction.

Comment: @user7795930 More code would be helpful. You should provide a **minimal, complete, and verifiable example** (even if not parallel yet): https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You have a **huge XY-problem** here. Simply use a `pragma omp parallel for reduction(<value to use>)` and let OpenMP do it's thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is the reduction needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819136/when-is-the-reduction-needed)