# OpenMP for loop using iterators gives incorrect results

Tags: c++, openmp

I wrote the following OpenMP program that uses an iterator as the loop index to compute the sum of elements of a vector but it does not print correct results:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
#define NT 10

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    int sum = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NT; i++)
        vec.push_back(i);

    k = vec.end() - vec.begin();
    printf("vec.end() - vec.begin() = %d\n", k);

    #pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(vec, sum) private(it)
    for (it = vec.begin(); it < vec.end(); it++) {
        #pragma critical
        sum += *it;
    }

    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
}
```

I get different values of sum on different runs of the program. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since `it` is declared outside of the loop shouldn't it be considered `shared` as well as `vec` and `sum`?

Comment: I have added 'private(it)' in the #pragma command, so it should be private.

Comment: I don't know the cause of this problem but using the following pragma solved this issue for me: `#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(vec) reduction(+:sum)`. You can even remove the `#pragma critical` if you use this.

Comment: Which version of openMP? Is it 3.0 or later? If not, change the loop to use an int, not an iterator. (VC++ uses 2.0)

Comment: I am using OpenMP 4.5 and I want to use iterators as loop index.

Comment: Found my problem; I should have used `#pragma omp critical` instead of `#pragma critical`.

Comment: Yes. Your compiler should warn you about that with proper warning levels. Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819136/when-is-the-reduction-needed - a reduction is much better in that case than a critical section.