# c++ threading in openmp

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Hello I'm having a hard time with this program, I'm supposed to go trough whole data vector sequentially and sum up each one of the vectors in there in parallel using openmp(and store the sum in solution[i]). But the program gets stuck for some reason. The input vectors that I'm given aren't many but are very large (like 2.5m ints each). Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Here is the code, ps: igone the unused minVectorSize parameter:

```
void sumsOfVectors_omp_per_vector(const vector<vector<int8_t>> &data, vector<long> &solution, unsigned long minVectorSize) {
    unsigned long vectorNum = data.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorNum; i++) {
#pragma omp parallel
        {
            unsigned long sum = 0;
            int thread = omp_get_thread_num();
            int threadnum = omp_get_num_threads();
            int begin = thread * data[i].size() / threadnum;
            int end = ((thread + 1) * data[i].size() / threadnum) - 1;

            for (int j = begin; j <= end; j++) {
                sum += data[i][j];
            }
#pragma omp critical
            {
                solution[i] += sum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is the reduction needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819136/when-is-the-reduction-needed)

Comment: Please stop posting our homework: https://cw.fel.cvut.cz/wiki/courses/b4b36pdv/tutorials/hw_02a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void sumsOfVectors_omp_per_vector(const vector<vector<int8_t>> &data, vector<long> &solution, unsigned long minVectorSize) {
unsigned long vectorNum = data.size();
for (int i = 0; i < vectorNum; i++) {
        unsigned long sum = 0;
        int begin = 0;
        int end = data[i].size();
        #omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
        for (int j = begin; j < end; j++) {
            sum += data[i][j];
        }

        solution[i] += sum;
}
}
```

Something like this should be more elegant and work better, Could you compile and comment if it works for you or doesnt

Comment: As a general rule it is smarter to lets omp distribute the work load for you and as @Nicolas Cami points out to parallelise the outermost loop. Unless you have some dependency that prevents this

Comment: thanks for the answer this works actually for the input i mentioned, but I have a follow up question, when i have input which consists of data where vectors have very varying lengths it runs for like 2 minutes but gives no reasonable output, why is that? I know that for input like that this approach isn't the best but it should give the right answer anyway right?

Comment: you mean "i"? But this would be a problem if len(solution) != len(data). If i goes out of bounds for either vector it will lead to undefined behaviour. Can you check the logic.

Comment: I meant to write: ...when I have input which..., ps: len(solution)==solution(data) I can vouch for that

Comment: Sorry for the confusion just noticed I wrote 'i' instead of 'I' in the beginning of the paragraph too

Comment: I can only be guessing here. But I think when j >> i, you will see good scaling. But if i >> j the overhead vs workload will make this non feasable. But no reasonable output means wrong output here?

Comment: nevermind I think I got it, the for loop:  "for (int j = begin; j <= end; j++)" should be  "for (int j = begin; j < end; j++)"  :P